# Conservar el formato de un rango al ejecutar una macro

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo, formato

Buen día,

Tengo un archivo en hoja de calculo de google, con una macro que guarda la información de algunas celdas en una base de datos en otra hoja, el detalle que presento es que  una celda tiene formato (texto sin formato) que contiene un codigo que inicia con 0 al guardar la información no conserva el formato de las celdas de origen y se pierde el 0, me podrian apoyar como puedo modificar mi el codigo de la macro para que se guarde con todo y elformato, seria la Celda D4.

saludos

```
 function Guardarcte() {
   var form = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Alta de cliente');
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


    var Codigocte = form.getRange('D4').getValue();
    var Empresa = form.getRange('E4').getValue();
    var RFC = form.getRange('D7').getValue();
    var RazonSocial = form.getRange('D8').getValue();      
    var Nombre1 = form.getRange('D9').getValue();
    var Correo1 = form.getRange('D10').getValue();
    var Telefono1 = form.getRange('D11').getValue();
    var Nombre2 = form.getRange('D12').getValue();
    var Correo2 = form.getRange('D13').getValue();
    var Telefono2 = form.getRange('D14').getValue();
    var Falta = form.getRange('D15').getValue();



    var Destino = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Base de datos cte');

    Destino.appendRow([Codigocte,Empresa,RFC,RazonSocial,Nombre1,Correo1,Telefono1,Nombre2,Correo2,Telefono2,Falta]);

  var form = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Alta cliente');
   var celda = hoja.getRange("D4");
    var valor = celda.getValue();
  var incremento = celda.setValue(valor+1);
   var form = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Alta cliente');

}
```

Comment: `appendRow` no interviene en el formato, por lo que podrías de antemano indicar el formato o los formatos que desees en las diferentes celdas / columnas de la hoja de destino. Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo de forma programática, tendrías que usar [`setNumberFormat()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=es-419#setnumberformatnumberformat).

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue lo primero que realice, agregar el formato en las celdas destino, pero al correr la macro, lo borra y lo cambia a formato autamatico y no guarda el 0 del inicio de mi codígo

Comment: El problema entonces debe estar en la macro, porque, como ya dije, `appendRow` no afecta el formato.